# How to configure CMake (in Clion) to work with Qt5.5.1 (open source) SDK?

Tags: c++, qt, cmake

I use CLion then additionally CMake. How to configure CMake to work with Qt5.5.1? Its my CMakeLists:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.3)
project(BennuEngine)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")
set(Qt5_DIR "~/programy/Qt5.5.1/5.5/gcc_64/lib/cmake/Qt5")
set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "~/programy/Qt5.5.1/5.5")

find_package(Qt5 REQUIRED MODULES Core)
file(GLOB_RECURSE SOURCE_FILES_BENNUENGINE "*.c" "*.cpp")
add_executable(BennuEngine ${SOURCE_FILES_BENNUENGINE})

target_include_directories(BennuEngine /usr/include/freetype2)
target_link_libraries(BennuEngine GL GLU GLEW freetype)
target_link_libraries(BennuEngine sfml-window sfml-graphics sfml-system sfml-audio sfml-network)
target_link_libraries(BennuEngine unittest++)
target_include_directories(BennuEngine PUBLIC src)
```

The error what I get is:

```
Error:Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Qt5MODULES" with any of the following names:
  Qt5MODULESConfig.cmake   qt5modules-config.cmake
Add the installation prefix of "Qt5MODULES" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set "Qt5MODULES_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "Qt5MODULES" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been installed.
```

Comment: Keyword for `find_package()` is `COMPONENTS`, not a `MODULES`.

Comment: @Tsyvarev, I have changed that. CLion now is saying that CmakeLists is ok, but when I put `#include <QString>` there is "header does not exists" error.

Comment: What about `include_directories()` and `target_link_libraries()` for link with QT libraries?

Comment: @Tsyvarev, I should put variable (from Qt CMake components) or what in those functions?

Comment: Try [this QT manual](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/cmake-manual.html) for use QT5 with CMake,

Comment: Adding the `qt5_use_modules(BennuEngine Core)` helped.

Comment: But usage of `qt5_use_modules` has been adviced in [Itha256's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34588269/3440745), and you commented that it is not helped.

Comment: Because at that time I had wrong `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use **find_package()** and then **qt5_use_modules()**.

This is what mine CMakeList looks like.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.3)
project(ELF_Scout)

set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")
set(SOURCE_FILES ...)
add_executable(ELF_Scout ${SOURCE_FILES})

if (WIN32)
    # If you compile on windows replace path to your Qt folder
    set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "C:\\Program Files\\Qt\\5.5\\mingw492_32\\lib\\cmake")
endif()
find_package(Qt5Core REQUIRED)
find_package(Qt5Widgets REQUIRED)
find_package(Qt5Gui REQUIRED)
qt5_use_modules(ELF_Scout Core Widgets Gui)
```